# Setting up go-gl on windows? GLFW not found?

Tags: opengl, go

I'm trying to get go-gl to work on windows. I've downloaded mingw and I've installed glfw according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886609/setting-up-glfw-with-mingw) (I put the dll in System32).

I download [triangle.go](https://github.com/go-gl/examples/blob/master/glfw3/triangle/triangle.go) from the examples github and setup this folder structure on my desktop:

```
/gocode
  /src
    /gogltest
      triangle.go
```

I set the `gocode` folder as the gopath, I `cd` into `gogltest` and run `go get`. It downloads the files into `gocode/src/github.com/` and I get this output:

```
# github.com/go-gl/glfw3
..\github.com\go-gl\glfw3\clipboard.go:4:24: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such
file or directory
 //#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
# github.com/go-gl/gl
In file included from ..\github.com\go-gl\gl\attriblocation.go:7:0:
gl.h:2:21: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GL/glew.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

What am I missing that will make glfw work for me?

Comment: You need to be able to build `github.com/go-gl/gl` first. Have you read through the README? There's [no confirmation of it working on windows](https://github.com/go-gl/gl#windows), but that's where you need to start.

Comment: I have read through that and the support is currently unknown. But I can't build go-gl/gl because mingw just can't find GLFW or GL despite the two files above being listed in `C:\MinGW\include\GLFW\glfw3.h` and `C:\MinGW\include\GL\glew.h`. Does `include` need to be in the path?

Comment: Just a heads up as well, if you get past this issue, there are a few bad import statements:

"github.com/go-gl/mathgl/examples/opengl-tutorial/helper"
"github.com/go-gl/mathgl/examples/opengl-tutorial/input"

I believe should be 

"github.com/go-gl/examples/mathgl/opengl-tutorial/helper"
"github.com/go-gl/examples/mathgl/opengl-tutorial/input"

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: that error is not related to GLFW at all, but to [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), which is an entirely different library.

Comment: @derhass I've gone down that road as well, but it doesn't do me any good to mess with GLEW if mingw's g++ can't find glfw3.h as well. I feel like fixing one missing file will direct me towards how to fix the second missing file.

Comment: @kwolfe -- Those are mine, can you send a pull request fixing the bad imports?