# glfw + codeblocks + undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'

Tags: c++, codeblocks, glfw

1) I've downloaded from http://www.glfw.org/download.html - glfw sources. Compiled them,
 got glfw.dll, libglfw.a, libglfwdll.a.

2) Put them step by step from those links:

[GLFW and codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856648/glfw-and-codeblocks)

to folders where they have to be.

3) Create new project in codeblocks.

And while building it (with default main.cpp, created by codeblocks) I got

```
undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
```

Here: [undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751640/undefined-reference-to-gxx-personality-sj0)
that problem described as problem of *compiled with different exception handling implementations*.

But really, I didn't changed anything in compiler settings, and I build glfw by myself, so it was not boult somewhere else with unknown exception handling.
So, exception handling (I really even don't know what is it and where can I change it) couldn't be changed since compiling glfw or main.cpp.

Please, help me solve that, to compile main.cpp, generated by CodeBlocks.
Thank you.

PS: I downloaded CodeBlocks from codeblocks.org (binary)
and then "MinGW + boost" from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html, and unzipped it over MinGW inside CodeBlocks. May that be problem?

Answer (score 0):

> problem described as problem of compiled with different exception handling implementations

in addition the compiler version must be the same while building glfw library
and compiling main.cpp

Comment: they were same.
"I downloaded CodeBlocks from codeblocks.org (binary) and then "MinGW + boost" from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html, and unzipped it over MinGW inside CodeBlocks." - that was done before I compiled both projects.